# Shadow path vs shadow in png

Tags: ios, core-graphics

Which is more efficient from a performance perspective: adding a shadow to a view with the shadow path or putting a shadow in the png for the background of the view? The view will be animating around the screen but not changing size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting a shadow in the PNG will always be more efficient because that is one less thing to calculate.  However, if you set your view's layer to rasterize (`view.layer.shouldRasterize`) then it will only recalculated when its size changes so the difference won't be big.